# turtlebot simulator warning

Tags: gazebo, simulation, turtlebot, turtlebot-simulator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

When I open turtlebot_gazebo by this

```
roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_empty_world.launch
```

((1)) Give me warning
[image: Raysensor]

((2)) want to know if there is a difference between Gazebo and Gazebo: default ?!

Thanks in Advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49976/turtlebot-simulator-warning-../) by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2012-12-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Don't worry about these warnings

---

Originally posted by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) with karma: 464 on 2013-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1